# Dynamically generated List Items Opens Dynamic Page jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a list generated with PHP.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-inset="true">
<?
  $qry = "SELECT jobname, jobsurname, LEFT(jobsurname, 1) AS first_char FROM clients  WHERE UPPER(LEFT(jobsurname, 1)) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z' OR LEFT(jobsurname, 1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9' ORDER BY jobsurname";  
  $result = mysql_query($qry);
  $current_char = '';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  if ($row['first_char'] != $current_char) {
     $current_char = $row['first_char'];
     echo '<li data-role="list-divider">' . strtoupper($current_char) . '</li>';
  }
echo '<li><a href="#">' . $row['jobsurname'] . ', ' . $row['jobname'] . '</a></li>';
}  

?>
</ul>
```

It lists everything like its supposed to. But I want each list item to open a dialog with the information strictly for that client. So do I run another SQL statement later on in my page creating more `<div data-role="page">` with an id matching the name or something? Or is there a way to call each info via ajax like:

```
echo '<li><a href="getInfo.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '" data-rel="dialog">' . $row['jobsurname'] . ', ' . $row['jobname'] . '</a></li>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep you can do it this way:

```
<a href="foo.html" data-rel="dialog">Open dialog</a>
```

The Docs:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/toolbars/../../docs/pages/docs-dialogs.html

So your code should work:

```
echo '<li><a href="getInfo.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '" data-rel="dialog">' . $row['jobsurname'] . ', ' . $row['jobname'] . '</a></li>';
```

Comment: So as long at getInfo.php?id=4 returns data...it opens in a dialog?

Comment: After some testing I did find a bug (if you call it that). The dialog will only display on local pages (No external sites). All my tests worked if the page was on my server, if I tried to link to www.google.com it didn't work

Comment: getInfo.php is a local file. The only concern I have is the ?id= part. I can also try adding `rel="external"` to the a tag

Comment: just tested and it works fine for me. The only problem you might have is the header as it adds a close button to the left side and this might cover up another element (I have a logo there) fyi. No Need to add the rel="external" tag

Comment: also you might want to add a transition to the anchor tag as well: data-transition="pop"

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1567#comment_1106448 read for more info on external links